# PromiseKit 6: Cannot invoke 'then' with an argument list of type '((String, String) -> Promise<Data>)'

Tags: swift, promise, promisekit

I have a `when(fulfilled: [Thenable])` that returns `Promise<(String, String)>`, however when I try to use these arguments in my `then` block I receive the following error:

> Cannot invoke 'then' with an argument list of type '((String, String) -> Promise)

My code is as follows:

```
func fetchAll(includeClosed: Bool) -> Promise<AccountInformation> {
    return when(fulfilled: [auth.currentUserIdPromise(), auth.getIdToken()])
        .then { (uid, token) in self.db.get(userID: uid, uri: "accounts", token: token) }
        .then { /* Some more stuff */ }
   }
}
```

In case it isn't clear, `auth.currentUserIdPromise()` and `auth.getIdToken()` both resolve to `String` and `db.get` returns a `promise`.

Things I've tried:

- Explicitly expressing types
- Clean and build

Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted this question to PromiseKit on GitHub and it turns out I was using the wrong 'when':

WAS: `return when(fulfilled: [auth.currentUserIdPromise(), auth.getIdToken()])`

NOW: `return when(fulfilled: auth.currentUserIdPromise(), auth.getIdToken())`

The former returns an array, whereas the latter returns a tuple.

https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/issues/943